# How to import an excel to sas with getnames = no?

Tags: sas

I want to specify new names so I use `getnames=no` property:

```
data mylib.test; 
   infile  "C:\Users\test.xlsx" ;
   input var1   $ Opened_Date mmddyy8.  salary dollar9.2;
   DBMS=EXCEL ;
   range="Sheet5$";
   getnames=no;
   mixed=no;
   scantext=yes;
   usedate=yes;
   scantime=yes;
   datarow=3;
run;
```

But this does not import anything

---

**PS** *the following code with `getnames=yes` works fine . This means that there is no problems with excel file . But i don't want to use `yes` I need `getnames=no`*

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= WORK.TEST 
            DATAFILE= "C:\Userstest.xlsx" 
            DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE;
     RANGE="Sheet5$"; 
     GETNAMES=YES;
     MIXED=NO;
     SCANTEXT=YES;
     USEDATE=YES;
     SCANTIME=YES;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= WORK.TEST 
            DATAFILE= "C:\Userstest.xlsx" 
            DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE;
     RANGE="Sheet5$"; 
     GETNAMES=NO;
     MIXED=NO;
     SCANTEXT=YES;
     USEDATE=YES;
     SCANTIME=YES;
RUN;
```

The data step is not helpful in this case.  You can't import an excel file that way (practically speaking).

After this, you then create a data step and can rename things however you want from the generic names initially assigned by the PROC IMPORT.

An alternative that looks like the data step method is `libname` access.

```
libname myexcel excel "c:\Usertest.xlsx" getnames=no scantext=yes mixed=no usedate=yes scantime=yes;
```

Then you can access the file like

```
data test;
set myexcel,'Sheet5$'n;
rename f1=var1 f2=opened_date (...more...);
run;
```

I tend to use PROC IMPORT as it's a bit easier to understand for others, but both are equivalent in how they work (PROC IMPORT creates this libname for you, basically).

Comment: Thank you . That's what I have been using so far . Apparently this is the only right way .

Comment: If you really want to use the data step, there is the `libname` access method, but that doesn't really save you anything in this particular example - you still need to rename/etc. the variables.